# To be able to toggle something

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

So I'm programming something, and it has the property to be toggled. Now I want to enable or disable this property. In other words, I want to toggle the toggle property.

This property, whether or not something can be toggled, should it be called '*Togglable*' ? If not, what **should** I call it?

Comment: Off topic (variable naming is off topic: see the [help]).

Comment: @MετάEd It's not about variable naming.. I asked if togglable was an English word, to be used in the context of programming.. To clarify my question, I gave some context, and jmadsen understood this context and responded to that. Though the main question remains: Is togglable an English word ;)

Comment: @JochemKuijpers As you said, the question remains. I submit that you should un-accept jmadsen's answer - the fact that the question accepts that answer is fundamental in the question's closure. If not for that, I would vote to reopen. (That and the fact that I don't have the rep for it. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding *-able* to transitive verbs is still a fairly productive process in today's English.

Since *toggle* is a transitive verb, you should be able to form *toggleable* (meaning "able to be toggled") and be understood, even if the reader has never seen the word before.  There are lexical exceptions which *-able* doesn't usually attach to (*beware*, *want*, *loathe*, etc.) but I don't believe *toggle* is one of them.

When you add *-able*, the syllablic /<sup>ə</sup>l/ in *toggle* is likely to become a regular /l/, becoming the onset of the following syllable.  This is called [**syncope**](http://www.pronuncian.com/Lessons/Default.aspx?Lesson=207) and is sometimes reflected in spelling--particularly in derivations like these as there's no history to force the spelling one way or the other--so you might instead spell it *togglable*.

Of course, as jmadsen points out, there's no reason you **have** to add *-able*.  But you can if you like.

Comment: As (another) programmer, I know I've used *toggleable* before. I slightly prefer this as it grammatically fits with Java bean standard of `object.isToggleable`.

Comment: I think rice pudding might be loathable. I simply have to decide whether it is actually loathsome or not.

Answer (score 1):

Also, *Toggleable*, with the ***e*** intact.

[togglable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/togglable#English) (Wiktionary)

> Able to be toggled. *That button is togglable.*

Usage example: See [Toggleable radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118229/toggleable-radio-buttons) on StackOverflow.

@LateralFractal is right in suggesting **isToggbleable** as appropriate for the OP's context. See usage on [GoogleSearch](https://www.google.com/#q=istoggleable+-toggleable).