# Is it "togglable" or "toggleable"?

Tags: orthography, suffixes, silent-letters, able-eable

The dialect is American English, but I'd be interested to know if this varies between dialects.  Is it"togglable" or "toggleable"?  Because neither dictionary.com, webster.com, nor Outlook's spelling suggestions/checker tend to have any record of this word.  I have a hard time believing it's not a word in proper English though, and I would be tempted to think its spelling is "toggleable".

Comment: Google's book search reveals 300 results for "toggleable" and 45 results for "togglable". Not a lot of traction on either word, but "toggleable" is more popular.

Comment: Why don't you believe it's not a word? Generally you would use "two-state widget" or "widget that can be toggled".

Comment: @KevinWorkman It seems to me like it makes too much sense for it to not be a word, even if it hasn't caught the attention of all the academic institutions yet.

Comment: @Panzercrisis I'm not sure that's enough to consider something a word, but you might want to check out the answers (especially snailboat's answer) to this question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132535/to-be-able-to-toggle-something

Comment: Syntactically and orthographically, ***to toggle*** is much the same as ***to handle***, where Google NGram makes it pretty obvious [most people still retain the 'e' in 'handleable'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=handlable%2Chandleable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chandlable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chandleable%3B%2Cc0). Contrast with ***sizable/sizeable***, where most people have discarded the 'e', and ***lovable/loveable***, where practically *everyone* has discarded it. Me, I'm just hopelessly inconsistent.

Comment: Related, possible duplicates: *[Rules for removing last vowel when adding “-able”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76043)*, *[When to drop the 'e' when ending in -able?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55193)*

Comment: The issue of whether to drop the "excess" vowel in a word like "toggleable" is a long-standing one.  There are "rules", but they generally come with long lists of exceptions.

Comment: Google web results ([toggleable](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=%22toggleable%22):284k, [togglable](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q="togglable"):321k) reinforce @IanMacDonald's cited Google Books Ngrams tallies, though I get ["Ngrams not found: toggleable, togglable"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=toggleable%2Ctogglable&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) when I try.

Comment: related: [Are you googlable?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296122/are-you-googlable)

Comment: @Kevin: Any word + valid affix = word. It's called "productive morphology."

Comment: @Ben As has been mentioned here before, productivity is gradeable in English.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's not a word, so it has no formal spelling as of now.  The English language's main strength is its adaptability, so one day it will most likely be officially accepted as a word, but for now, it has no defined spelling.

I would personally keep the e, as there are 3 consonants before it, and that makes me want to balance the scales a bit, and that's how it works in some others with the same scenario, like settleable, whistleable, and handleable.

Comment: Why do you say it's not a word? Just because it's not in a dictionary? If you're waiting for it to be "officially accepted as a word", you'll be waiting a long time, since there is no official organization with the power to do so. Anyway, I agree with the spelling suggested here.

Comment: Good point, I'm going with a technical not-a-word thing. There aren't any official organizations that represent the English language, sure, but Merriam-Webster qualifies in my eyes. Once they add a word, I consider it "official."

Comment: What about when it gets added to wiktionary? Or when it shows up > 500k times in Google? There simply is no "official" recognition of words in English, and arguably if two people use it and understand each other, it's already a word.

Comment: @friff14: *"...a technical not-a-word thing..."* Again: There is no such thing, for English. If there were, it certainly wouldn't be Merriam-Webster; the OED, more likely. But they are clear their role (indeed, the role of English dictionaries in general) is *descriptive*, not prescriptive.

Comment: I know this discussion is quite stale, but I've been saying for many years that "Common usage is correct usage" (in absence of a named style guide). If people readily understand toggleable to mean "something with two states that will transition back and forth between those states upon a discrete action" then it's a word.
As far as leaving the 'e', I'd say it stays because the pronunciation in practice as far as I've heard is ˈtɒgələbəl not ˈtɒglɑːbəl (Tog-uhl-uh-bull not Tog-la-bull) contrast lovable where the v blends into the able.

Comment: Is it still not a word? Any idea when it will be added to dictionaries or started being considered as a word? I think it's used quite often in context of different togglable settings or video games' related things, like abilities, recently even more.